# JQuery image carousel animation, works going one way but not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

The code is pretty short, here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4Ry3/170/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#previous_frame').on("click",function(){
        var $last = $('.frames li:last-child')
        $('.frames').prepend($last)
        $last.css({left:'-33%'})
        $last.animate({left:'0%'})
    });

    $('#next_frame').on("click",function(){
        var $first = $('.frames li:first-child');
        $('.frames').append($first);
        $('.frames li:first-child').css({right:'-33%'});
        $('li:first-child').animate({right:'0%'})
    });
})
```

If I click the left button, it slowly moves the image.  When I click the right side, the image instantaneously switches into position.  I can't understand why this would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `left` rule you add. It stays 0. You can notice it works at first, then stops working for images you clicked left on, but keeps working for the rest.

In the `next_frame` function add

```
$('.frames li:first-child').css({left:''});
```

to remove that `left`.

You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/L4Ry3/185/).

Test it out by clicking left all through, then clicking right again.

### In Depth

Apparently the `left` style rule is more dominant than the `right`. When you have both it regards only the `left`, so though the `right` is animating, it stays on 0% left. Removing the `left` rule allows the css engine to regard the `right` and show the desired animation.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong but it still doesn't work (in the fiddle you gave) going right...  But the answer makes sense.

Comment: Oh I just realized that you may have typo'd in the last animation.  It's supposed to be right: 0, not left: 0.  Now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change the `right` to `left` in your next frame click event and `-` to `+`..that should do the trick

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#previous_frame').on("click",function(){
    var $last = $('.frames li:last-child')
    $('.frames').prepend($last)
    $last.css({left:'-33%'})
    $last.animate({left:'0%'})
});

$('#next_frame').on("click",function(){
    var $first = $('.frames li:first-child');
    $('.frames').append($first);
    $('.frames li:first-child').css({left:'33%'}); //<----here
    $('li:first-child').animate({left:'0%'})//<----here
});
})
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Ry3/179/)